# Vuejs Range Slider - Mark boundaries with labels

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, web-frontend

I'm currently using the range slider from vuetify (V2)

My point is to define a range, between 0 to 12 for 3 types (50%, 75% and 100%)

So I thought if I define a range, between to points I can have 3 spaces to define the boundaries

With that I'm ok.
My question is:

Is there a way to put a label between the ranges, like the following image?

https://prnt.sc/5NoTOETIY8Mg

Maybe we could mark a point in the slider, between the rangers. But how?
Or another way

I'm stucked with this. Some ideas?

Note that the ranges can change. And its possible to have the slider with the 2 points at 12
That should count only a 50% range

https://prnt.sc/2JYtqh2APrn1

Or we can have just 50% and 75% with no 100%

https://prnt.sc/ifGIyD4ec2xn

I would appreciate some ideas of how to do that and thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduction.

Comment: the reproduction is made by hand. Marked with the red numbers. Cant reproduce in code because I have no idea how to do that :(

Comment: https://prnt.sc/5NoTOETIY8Mg